# C# how to make for looping like this in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

i want to ask how to make looping like this :

Views in console like this :

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
5 15
6 21
7 28
```

I already know how to do this

```
int i;
int y = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    for (int x = 1; x < 7; x += i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + x);
    }
}
```

But that produces output of:

```
1 
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
2  
    1
    3
    5
3
    1
    4
4 
    1
    5
5  
    1
    6
6
    1
7
    1
```

Comment: Are you posting a puzzle for us to find the pattern of `1 1 2 3 3 6 4 10 5 15 6 21 7 28` ?

Comment: It's also not clear why you'd expect the current code to do anything different. Please be specific in what you're asking - which shouldn't boil down to "Show me the code to produce this output".

Comment: Hint: I suspect you're fine having a nested loop, but you don't want to write any output in that loop... you just want to add up the numbers. And your nested loop shouldn't be adding `i` each time...

Comment: i want to like the first view.

Comment: i am new in this forum. sorry my question so terrible

Comment: like 1 1
      2 3 , 3 is from 1 + 2 cross to the bottom. how make like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a guess but try this:

```
int addition = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, i+addition);

    addition = i+addition;
}
```

It helps sometimes to explicitly write down the problem for oneself in real language. Like in this case.

How does the expected output come about in each line?

It seems that the right number is the sum of the left number and the right number of the previous line.

So you need to calculate a **sum** and **remember** the number from the previous summation. And this is already the algorithm that you need.

Hope it helps

Comment: GREAT! it is what i want. thank you very much for answer my problem sir. Thanks A lot. God Bless you.

Comment: you are welcome. I suggest really to try it, this way you start thinking in algorithm form, and if you have done it a 100 times you will develop an eye for such problems and see the solution right away. But first you have to go through the effort of thinking through every step of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want to print out *traingular numbers*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

in order to do this you can use *Linq*:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(1, 7)
    .Select(i => $"{i} {i * (i + 1) / 2}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

An alternative *for loop* implementation:

```
  for (int i = 1, a = 1; i <= 7; i++, a += i)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i} {a}");
```

Outcome:

```
1 1
2 3
3 6
4 10
5 15
6 21
7 28
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
int i;
int y = 1;

for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    /*Console.WriteLine(i);*/ // NOT NEEDED
    for (int x = 1; x < 7; x += i)
    {
        /*Console.WriteLine("\t" + x);*/ // WRONG
        Console.WriteLine(i+"\t" + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: almost right, but why the total is not 28?
i want the left number always add the right number, not decrease

Answer (score 0):

```
int y = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    y = i + y;
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " " + y.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output you need. This code would help you get the desired output.

```
int addition = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    addition += i;
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + addition);
}
```

Secondly we always wont require to have a nested loop. In your case we have the second column but we can manipulate the second number in one liner itself. So Just use one loop to get

> ```
> 1 1
> 2 3
> 3 6
> 4 10
> 5 15
> 6 21
> 7 28
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
      int[] input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    List<int> output = new List<int>();
    int i;
    int k = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        output.Add(input[i]);
        output.Add(input[i] + y);
        y = output.Last();
        z = output.Count;
        for (int j = k; j < z; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(output[j] + " ");
        }
        k = output.Count;
        Console.WriteLine();
```